# Returning a list of custom post types excluding those without a specific meta_value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

**UPDATE: I think I'm on the right path with some of the help from the meta query options, but I might've gone overboard as it's extremely inefficient. You can see the updated code in the bottom of this post.**

I technically have three questions for this, but they're related and require the first to be answered, so I hope it's okay to post all here.

To put this in a little context, I'm working on a directory of sorts where I can add to 3 URLs in 3 meta fields for each post. I want to display a list of only posts that have 1-3 of said URLs added. To make this extra interesting, I also have 3 corresponding checkboxes to each meta field that I can select in case an item is sold out. I would like to exclude sold out items from this list as well.

**Question 1 - How do I display a list of custom post type posts that all have the same meta_value and key (excluding those that have the same value)**

I've managed to make a list that returns all `myPostType` posts where `'meta_value' => false` in `myMetaKey`. See code below:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myPostType', 
        'meta_key' => 'myMetaKey', 
        'meta_value' => false, 
        'orderby' => '_custom', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

I am interested in having a list that returns posts that *does* have a `meta_value` in `myMetaKey`. I thought it would be as simple as to change `false` to `true` in `meta_value`, but that returns an empty list instead.

**SOLVED: Question 2 - How do I return a list that includes posts with different `meta_key`'s?**

I'm interested in also having the list display posts from `myPostType` that have both `myMetaKeyA`, `myMetaKeyB` and `myMetaKeyC` - but only if `meta_value` is true (or the equivalent as asked above in questions 1).

> Thanks to Niels who directed me to the `meta_query` class. Adding multiple arrays to `meta_query` did the trick.

**Question 3 - How do I exclude posts that have a `meta_key` with a corresponding checkbox selected**

As mentioned in the beginning I'm also interested in excluding posts via a selected checkbox.

---

**I think I fixed a lot of my issues, but my code is so inefficient that it's practically useess**.

As it is below it takes more than 30 mins. to load (as in I closed the tab after 30 mins.). Does anyone have any pointers as to how to rewrite this more efficiently?

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('myPostType1', 'myPostType2'), 
    'orderby' => '_custom', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR',
      array('relation' => 'AND',
          array(
            'key' => 'product1',
            'value' => false,
            'compare' => '!=',
            ),
          array(
            'key' => 'stock1',
            'value' => '"soldOut1"',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            )
          ),
      array('relation' => 'AND',
          array(
            'key' => 'product2',
            'value' => false,
            'compare' => '!=',
            ),
          array(
            'key' => 'stock2',
            'value' => '"soldOut2"',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            )
          ),
      array('relation' => 'AND',
          array(
            'key' => 'product3',
            'value' => false,
            'compare' => '!=',
            ),
          array(
            'key' => 'stock3',
            'value' => '"soldOut3"',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            )
          )
        )
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your current code I think you missed the WP Meta Query class which can do what you want;

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thank you for this. That solved question 2 for me with adding multiple arrays to the meta_query being quite a simple task. However, I still cannot seem to figure out how to exclude posts with no `meta_value` for the URLs. I assume it's got something to do with the `compare` argument, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.